# On two-dimensional non-singular complete toric varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $v_0,v_1,\dots,v_d=v_0$ be a sequence of lattice points in $\mathbb Z^2$, in counterclockwise order (see figure below), such that successive pairs generate $\mathbb Z^2$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module.

[image]

I am trying to prove the following -

1. Show that if $d\ge4$ there must be two opposite vectors in the sequence, i.e., $v_j=-v_i$ for some $i,j$.
2. Suppose $v_i=-v_0$ and $i\ge3$, show that $v_j=v_{j-1}+v_{j+1}$

I have shown that $v_0,\cdots,v_d$ satisfy the following -

(a) $a_jv_j=v_{j-1}+v_{j+1}$ , $1\le i\le d$, for some integers $a_i$ and these integers satisfy, $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&a_1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&a_2\end{array}\right)\cdots\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&a_d\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$$

(b) Two cones $\langle v_i,v_{i+1}\rangle$ and $\langle v_j,v_{j+1}\rangle$ cannot be arranged with $v_j$ in the angle strictly between $v_{i+1}$ and $-v_i$ **and** $v_{j+1}$ in the angle strictly between $-v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$.

I know i have to use (b) somehow to prove 1 but I am unsure how. Help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a counterexample with these 4 vectors : $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thats not a valid counterexample, because you have to change the third and fourth vector in order for them to be given counterclockwise. But then you can see that the toric variety given by them is singular.

Comment: You can actually prove it simply in the case $d=3$ by assuming that $v_0=e_1$ and $v_1=e_2$ and then using the determinant condition. But I don't see how to generalize this easily.

Comment: I meant $d=4$...

Comment: Actually the vectors are in counter clockwise direction. The problem is that the resulting fan isn't complete. Thank you for your comments @Maik Pickl

Comment: You are rigth. I was confusing the axes for the last two vectors.